# Time-dependent flow of $X$ and $-X$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $X$ is a vector field on a manifold $M$ then we know $$\Phi^{-X}_t=\Phi_{-t}^X.$$ How is the flow of $X$ related to the flow of $-X$ in the time dependent case?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first formula cannot possibly be true, as it would imply $\Phi_0^{-X}$ is not the identity. You want $\Phi^X_{-t}$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Agreed, thanks =)

Comment: What are your assumptions on the time dependence of X? Is it arbitrary time dependence, periodic, Hamiltonian, etc?

Comment: It is arbitrary. $X$ is just a smooth map $X:\mathbb R\times M\longrightarrow TM$ such that $X(t, p)\in T_pM$ for every $p\in M$ (where $M$ is a manifold).